# How can I make a custom memory allocation for classes with virtual methods?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, memory-efficiency, memory

I want to create a custom allocator that stores objects to the heap sequentially. The allocator itself is very simple. It just allocates a big chunk of memory and moves an offset as `Allocate()` calls happen.

The problem comes when allocating memory for custom types, especially classes with virtual functions.

```
SomeClassWithVirtualFunctions * address = array_allocator->Allocate(sizeof(SomeClassWithVirtualFunctions));
SomeClassWithVirtualFunctions->Init(...);
```

It throws a seg fault when the virtual function is called, since as i am given to understand, stuff that are initialized through the constructor (vtable for example) are now ignored.

However, if i do the following,

```
SomeClassWithVirtualFunctions * the_new_object = new SomeClassWithVirtualFunctions();
char * memory = array_allocator->Allocate(sizeof(*the_new_object));
memcpy(memory, the_new_object, sizeof(*the_new_object));
SomeClassWithVirtualFunctions->Init();
```

then the code works fine. I believe though that the above is a dangerous work-around trick.

The intend is to have a base class with virtual functions like `Step()` for example, that game classes like `Player, Grass, Wall` override to have unique behavior.

What is the best way to implement this? Do i use the custom allocator to store only primitive class members stuff, and classes are allocated normally?

Will overriding the `new` operator for `SomeClassWithVirtualFunctions` work?

```
void * operator new(size_t size) {
    char * address = array_allocator->Allocate(size);

    return address;
}
```

Comment: This one seems to me to fall foul of the "would a game developer give me a better answer?" test - the answer to that being "no".  What you want is called **placement new** - see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [std::allocator_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) that will allow you to use your allocator and construct objects in allocated space.

If you don't want to use that you can use placement new: `new(the_new_object) SomeClassWithVirtualFunctions(...)` keep in mind that you will need to use `the_new_object->~SomeClassWithVirtualFunctions()` to deconstruct it before you can return it to the allocator for reuse.

You can also pass other parameters to the new overload

```
void * operator new(size_t size, array_allocator_t array_allocator) {
    char * address = array_allocator->Allocate(size);

    return address;
}
```

call with `new(array_allocator) SomeClassWithVirtualFunctions(...)`